# <pluginRepository> in parent pom is ignored when parent pom is accessed through repository

Tags: maven

I have company maven repository. I have company super `pom.xml` with sections `<repository>` and `<pluginRepository>` pointing to company repo. Company super pom is separated artifact.

I develop my maven project. Parent pom is company super pom. In order to pass build on clean environment I need to define again `<repository>` in my project home because Maven must know where parent pom can be found (see [Catch-22](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/#.VmARhr9xKpo))

I'm not happy that I have define to company repository again in my project but I accepted it.

In my project I use company plugin. The problem is that Maven cannot find company plugin. It is strange because maven finds super pom with `<pluginRepository>` but does not use the plugin repository to find the plugin! So I have to define again `<pluginRepository>`

Super pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>company-repo</id>
        <url>http://mycompany.com/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>company-repo</id>
        <url>http://mycompany.com/repo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My project pom:

```
<!-- required to find company super pom - unhappy but accepted-->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>company-repo</id>
        <url>http://mycompany.com/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<!-- required to find company plugin - unhappy and hard to accept-->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>company-repo</id>
        <url>http://mycompany.com/repo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Question: Is is possible to avoid repeat plugin repository configuration in each Maven project? Maybe I should change my desing/configuration/whatever?

What interesting, `<pluginRepositories>` is not required if super pom is accessed through relative path instead of through repository.

Maven 3.3.3

UPDATE:

If I remove `<pluginRepositories>` from my project pom then effective-pom does NOT show company-repo as plugin repository. I wish.

Comment: Better go via `settings.xml` file instead.

Comment: I see 2 problems with `settings.xml`. 1  - build is not portable 2 - I need to define `<pluginRepositories>` within section `<profiles>` When I choose some profile on build I mean: this build has something specific what is not used by other builds. But plugin repository is required for all builds and therefore should not be configured as profile. Compare: every morning I decide to wear long trousers or shorts. That is profile. But regardless of trousers I wear pants. Pants are not profile. Plugin repository is pants. Not profile.

Comment: You should configure a single mirror in settings.xml and that's it...What is not portable? Do you use a repository manager ? And profiles does not make sense...

Comment: *Portable* means all you need is checkot from repo and call mvn install. *Not portable* means build needs additional work - here edit settings.xml. Anyway, now is clear to me that you propose to configure `<mirrors>` section in settings.xml. It sounds reasonable. Please feel encouraged to compose complete answer

Comment: Does the plugin repository declared in the parent POM appear in the output of `mvn help:effective-pom`?

Comment: You should have configured the `settings.xml` only once during the on boarding of a developer that's it...

Comment: Isn't this a Maven bug? https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance states that `<pluginRepositories>` is inherited. If it's a bug, it should be reported and fixed. It would be nice to get some clarity on this.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to [setup your `settings.xml` file like this:](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html)

```xml
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And using a repository manager makes life easier...Apart from that you can of course use a [single pom which could be made](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/). But using a parent can't be changed for the developer and you can't change on a CI solution (like Jenkins) to configure their the appropriate `settings.xml`

Comment: What about limit solution to `<mirrors>` section only? Is looks suffcient: due `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` any download request will be handled by company repository.

Comment: BTW, it a bit strange that in comment you wrote ` And profiles does not make sense...` but solution mainly base on profiles...

Comment: khmarbaise, please see my comment to the OP. I've had some similar issues that so far I haven't been able to boil down into a small example and reproduce. It would be helpful to know whether this is a bug or what. Any thoughts? I'm asking because I saw you answer a lot of Maven questions, and I saw your name in the Maven JIRA and (I think) release notes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very late answer to this question, I believe I ran into the same problem and it's not actually an issue with Maven. We are using Artifactory as a local store for artifacts and it's set up to strip repository/pluginRepository information when you download poms. This behaviour can be disabled in the config panel for the repository.

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-5343

I imagine you were running into the same problem with Artifactory.